# Анимация переходов между страницами VueJS

Tags: vue.js

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <router-view v-if="ready" id="content"></router-view>
  <div id="wait" v-else></div>
</transition>
```

Использую вот такой код для анимирования (исчезает и появляется). Все работает кроме 1 случая.
Есть страницы, которые используют один темплейт. И если делать переход между ними, то анимация не срабатывает, просто резко меняется контент и все.
Это можно как то исправить? или писать свой костыль?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить параметр `key` к `router-view` `:key="'page' + $route.params.id"`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.